# Apply Migrations for EF 6 Code First - no context type was found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, .net-4.8

I am working on WCF .NET Framework 4.8 project and its WCF is self-hosted in a Console application.

I have set up the defined POCO classes and `DbContext` in their own separate project that is referenced by the WCF console app.

I have declared the *Connection String* for the `DbContext` in the app.config within the main console app.

When I try to execute the EF Code First commands like `EnableMigrations` and `Add-Migration` they fail to execute with the error:

`No context type was found in the assembly 'MAL.App.ConsoleHost'`

[image: Package Manager Console Error]

### console application App.Config

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="AppDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MySQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

### Data Class Library

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AlbumType> AlbumTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

### One POCO class

```
public class Album
{
    public Guid AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public Guid ArtistID { get; set; }
    public Guid AlbumTypeID { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public AlbumType AlbumType { get; set; }

}
```

### Console Main Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceHost hostMusicService = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWebServices));
    hostMusicService.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Web Services Started. Press [Enter] To Exit  ");
    Console.ReadLine();

    hostMusicService.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when your DbContext is defined in a separate project to your main runtime and your main runtime is set as the *Default Project* in the solution.

When the Package Manager Console is first opened, it assumes that the Solution *Default Project* is the project that you to execute commands against like `Enable-Migrations`.

You could change the *Default Project* of the solution, but a simpler way around it is to change or set the default project in the Package Manager console to the project that has your `AppDbContext` definition, as this is the project that you want the *Migrations* to be managed in.

[image: Changing the default project in the package manager console]

Here's the catch though, still leave your *Default Project* in the **Solution** as your console app.

- The solution *Default Project* is more than just the project that will execute when you hit F5 to run, this is the project that is used any time that Visual Studio needs to access an app/web config file at runtime.
- This was the same for the previous versions of EF with the EDMX design surface and even before that with DataSet designers, the connection strings from the *Default Project* config file were the ones the VS used at design time.

You can also use the `-ProjectName` argument to most of the EF CLI commands to pass in the name of the project instead of using the default. For brevity, I usually reserve this for scenarios where there are multiple projects that have contexts or especially when there are multiple contexts in the same project. You don't want to have to type out the project name *every time* you want to `Add-Migration` or `Update-DataBase` or for any other scaffold commands like this.

To get information about the supported arguments, use the `-?` switch after the command in the console:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -?

NAME
    Enable-Migrations
    
SYNOPSIS
    Enables Code First Migrations in a project.
    
    
SYNTAX
    Enable-Migrations [-ContextTypeName <String>] [-EnableAutomaticMigrations] [-MigrationsDirectory <String>] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ContextProjectName <String>] [-ConnectionStringName <String>] 
    [-Force] [-ContextAssemblyName <String>] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Enable-Migrations [-ContextTypeName <String>] [-EnableAutomaticMigrations] [-MigrationsDirectory <String>] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ContextProjectName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> 
    -ConnectionProviderName <String> [-Force] [-ContextAssemblyName <String>] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
    
    
DESCRIPTION
    Enables Migrations by scaffolding a migrations configuration class in the project. If the
    target database was created by an initializer, an initial migration will be created (unless
    automatic migrations are enabled via the EnableAutomaticMigrations parameter).
    

RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Enable-Migrations -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Enable-Migrations -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Enable-Migrations -full".

PM>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I need to run migration before I can use MyDbContext and I am unable to do so. I am sure console application and don't have any web front in this project. I have added screen shot of error above in question

Comment: found the answer. refer above please

Comment: That works too, but its a lot to type out every time, just set the default project in the package manager console it simplifies interacting on the command line

Comment: Its one of those things that isn't documented a lot, mainly because most of the examples are simplified right down to a single project, I would suggest it is more common to structure solutions with EF context and POCOs in different projects just as you have. Once you figure these things out, you don't forget it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. You need to add the Data Class Library Project Name in Migration as below;

```
- Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere -StartUpProjectName MyStartUpProjectNameHere -Verbose

- add-migration Initial -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere

-  update-database -ProjectName MyContextProjectNameHere
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command may help.

> EntityFrameworkCore\enable-migrations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31254436)